# Filesystem- ext4 : Application corrupting superblock

Tags: c, filesystems, ext4, superblock

I found many links but almost all are pointing to fix not the reason.

I created a 7GB ext4 partition on a sd card connected via USB card reader to PC. I have an application which is writing 10488576 bytes to the mentioned partition (/dev/sdc2). After the application run the filesystem is looking corrupt:

```
#fsck.ext4 -v /dev/sdc2
e2fsck 1.42.8 (20-Jun-2013)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext4: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
Superblock has an invalid journal (inode 8).
Clear<y>? no
fsck.ext4: Illegal inode number while checking ext3 journal for /dev/sdc2

/dev/sdc2: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****

/dev/sdc2: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********



#dumpe2fs /dev/sdc2
dumpe2fs 1.42.8 (20-Jun-2013)
dumpe2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdc2
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

The application is simply using something like below (i can't post exact code):

```
    char *write_buf; //declared in header
    write_buf = (char *) malloc(size) // where size = 10488576. This allocation is happening in function a() called from main
    char *buf; // declared locally in function b()
    buf = write_buf; // in function b()
    write(fd,buf,size); // in function b()
```

The filesystem block size is 4K.
Backup superblock at 32768 , 98304 ,163840 ,229376 , 294912 ,819200, 884736 ,1605632
Let me know if any more information required. I need to understand what might cause this corruption , because I'm very much affirmative that something may be wrong with application code.

**`EDIT:`**
 I can see that primary superblock starts at 0 , and the lseek() call before `write()` is also doing `SEEK_SET` to 0, which would overwrite superblock information. I am going to try lseek far from superblock before `write()`.

**`EDIT`:**
I have got this fixed by doing as I mentioned above. As per dumpe2fs o/p I had below for group 0:

```
Group 0: (Blocks 0-32767)
  Checksum 0x8bba, unused inodes 8069
  Primary superblock at 0, Group descriptors at 1-1
  Reserved GDT blocks at 2-474
  Block bitmap at 475 (+475), Inode bitmap at 491 (+491)
  Inode table at 507-1011 (+507)
  24175 free blocks, 8069 free inodes, 2 directories, 8069 unused inodes
  Free blocks: 8593-32767
  Free inodes: 12-8080
```

So before writing I did lseek to 8593*4096 .Now filesystem is not getting corrupt.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear: 

are you writing 10488576 bytes to a file residing on an ext4 filesystem mounted from `/dev/sdc2`, or are you actually opening `/dev/sdc2` directly and writing do it?

Comment: Because if it is the second, by definition this will corrupt the filesystem...

Comment: Writing raw data to a partition ruins the partition, as you're overwriting all the overhead stuff (including the magic number, which your mounting software is clearly picking up.)

Comment: @6EQUJ5 Yes, the application is opening /dev/sdc2 and then doing write() on the retrived fd . So according to your comment that's the problem it seems. Is mmap() of some help here? Can you suggest the better way please.

Comment: Mount the file system and then write to it ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got this fixed by doing as I mentioned above. As per dumpe2fs o/p I had below for group 0:

```
Group 0: (Blocks 0-32767)
  Checksum 0x8bba, unused inodes 8069
  Primary superblock at 0, Group descriptors at 1-1
  Reserved GDT blocks at 2-474
  Block bitmap at 475 (+475), Inode bitmap at 491 (+491)
  Inode table at 507-1011 (+507)
  24175 free blocks, 8069 free inodes, 2 directories, 8069 unused inodes
  Free blocks: 8593-32767
  Free inodes: 12-8080
```

So before writing I did `lseek` to 8593*4096.Now filesystem is not getting corrupt.